# Count Drawdown / Run-up in a strategy. Which one hit first?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am trying to analyze closed trade performance on 2 factors, drawdown per trade and run-up per trade.
Is it possible to analyze how many trades hit drawdown value first and how many hit run-up value first?

Can we analyze if the price went down first (i.e. hit drawdown first) and then went up (i.e. Run-up) or vice versa?
If yes, then can we count them and display them on the chart?

```
Drawdown first = 56 Trades
Run-up first = 44 Trades
Total = 100 Trades
```

For e.g. Reference picture attached[image: List of trades showing Drawdown% and Run-up%].

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes and yes
Long answer: It is quite a difficult task that probably won't get solved here on stackoverflow. You need to track the price very closely yourself in pine script, maybe even intraday depending on your strategy and store your results in a matrix. (That's what I'd do) At the end you can then display everything in a table.
Huge task, but here are some references that may help you get started:
[pine script manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/) where you can look up some methods you might use for that, but these are just possibilities and the list will not be complete either, I just want to give you some thoughs that might help you:
*matrix, table, ta.highest(), ta.change() request.security_lower_tf()*
Also you may find some helpful scripts where you can get some ideas like using matrices or tables on [tradingview](https://www.tradingview.com/script/mGF7bMPS-Strategy-BackTest-Display-Statistics-TraderHalai/).